# when this code prints it has a 0. how do I get it to print without it?

Tags: python

How do I get this to return a list without a 0

```
import calendar

for i, m in enumerate (calendar.month_name):
    print(i,m)
```

It prints like this.

```
0 
1 January
2 February
3 March
4 April
5 May
6 June
7 July
8 August
9 September
10 October
11 November
12 December
```

Getting rid of the 0 on the first line is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The question subject says how to print without it, the question body asks how you returns it. Which do you want?

Comment: change `print(i,m)` to `print(i+1,m)`

Comment: Should have visited [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) of `enumerate`.

Comment: Commenters: the root of the problem, which the question doesn't make clear, is that `month_name` produces a "null" month at the beginning of the sequence. The output as is starts with `(0, '')`, not `(1, 'January')`. Whether the goal is to return a list or output the months isn't really relevant, nor is the advice to simply add 1 to `i`.

Comment: this worked for i, m in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:], 1):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`month_name`' "helpfully" pads the list with an empty string so that the list indices match up with the normal 1-based counting of the months. To work around this, I would slice the list and enumerate it with an explicit starting point of 1.

```
for i, m in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:], 1):
```

Another, more cumbersome but possibly useful, method is to get an explicit iterator for the list and "pre-advance" it.

```
month_itr = iter(calendar.month_name)
next(month_itr)
for i, m in enumerate(month_itr, 1):
```

This might be more efficient than creating a new list, but depending on your use case the difference may be irrelevant.

Using `itertools` to do something similar:

```
from itertools import islice

# The explicit stop=None tells islice to go to the end of the iterable
for i, m in enumerate(islice(calendar.month_name, 1, None), 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they use an empty string in the first entry in the list to keep the months aligned with their numbers (ie: January is number 1) as Python begins indexing at 0. You can check out the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name

You could just split the list to keep only the entries you want:

```
calendar.month_name[1:]
```